# Little oh notation in probability: $P(X_n = 0)=1-\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, asymptotics

Let $\{X_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of random variables with probability distribution given by:

$$P(X_n = 1)= \frac{1}{n} \quad \text{and } \quad P(X_n = 0)=1-\frac{1}{n} $$

Prove that $X_{n}= o_p(1)$.

I can't understand how is possible to prove that $X_{n}= o_p(1)$ since $P(X_n=0)$ goes to $1$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: So $X_n/1$ goes to $0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X_n=o_p(1)$ means for any $\epsilon >0$ there exist $k$ such that $P(|X_n | >k) <\epsilon$. See [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjujqWiutPsAhUvyDgGHfzXAUYQFjABegQIBxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stat.purdue.edu%2F%7Edasgupta%2Fessasy.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1Ey18zAg8UFH6T1kBo95Ts).  Just take any $k >1$: You get $P(|X_n | >k)=0 <\epsilon$.